# Java Formatting width with printf; '$' not moving with number

Tags: java, formatting, printf

Wondering how I can place the '$' sign so it moves with the number when i do this:

```
    System.out.printf("$%20.2f", test);
```

i get

```
$               10.00
```

I'm trying to format a series of data into 3 columns

I've tried placing the $ after the % like in C but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shortcut to add text to the variable to be formatted.
You will have to do this in two steps, like this:

```
System.out.printf("%20s", String.format("$%.2f", test));
```

Comment: Thanks Keppil. This answer was more appropriate and closer to what we learnt

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a kludge but I normally just set up a decimal formatter for this:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // One-time setup (could be simpler, I've opted for readability).
        final String fmt20v2a = "$#################.00";
        final String fmt20v2b = "%21s";
        final DecimalFormat df20v2 = new DecimalFormat (fmt20v2a);

        // Usage
        System.out.printf(fmt20v2b + "\n", df20v2.format(74.1));
        System.out.printf(fmt20v2b + "\n", df20v2.format(999999.99));
```

}
}

This gives you aligned output with a bit of extra work, but the setup generally only has to be done once. Output of that is:

```
              $74.10
          $999999.99
```

Comment: During my google search before I posted this I did come across this answer but was reluctant to use it as we haven't been taught it yet. But not to say it's a wrong way just might not get marks for it.